# How to convert model with array to JSON array Swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

i have some question and solution, i have class model and it has array inside, my model like this

```
class WillModel{
    var name: String = ""
    var documents:[WillItems] = []
    var isLFStatus : Bool = false
    var isLFShared : Bool = false
}

class WillItems{
    var documentPath: String = ""
    var documentRemark: String = ""
}
```

i want to convert the result to JSON Array like

```
{
 "name" : "value",
 "documents" : [
      {
       "documentPath" : "value"
       "documentRemark" : "value"
       },
      {
       "documentPath" : "value2"
       "documentRemark" : "value2"
      }
      ],
 "isLFStatus" : true,
 "isLFShared" : true
}
```

i'm using Swift 3, thanks for your solutions

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I highly recommend to update to Swift 4 and adopt `Codable`, `JSONEncoder` can do it in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple method to manually `encode` your `model` to `json` as below,

```
func encodeWillModel(_ model: WillModel) -> [String: Any] {
    var params: [String: Any] = [:]
    params["name"] = model.name
    params["documents"] = model.documents.map({["documentPath": $0.documentPath,
                                                "documentRemark": $0.documentRemark]})
    params["isLFStatus"] = model.isLFStatus
    params["isLFShared"] = model.isLFShared
    return params
}
```

and you can pass any model to get the json something like,

```
let willModelJSON = encodeWillModel(yourModel)
```

But a better approach would be to use any `json` parsing library([SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)) that supports `Swift 3` or upgrade to `Swift 4` and use `Encodable/Decodable`

Comment: @j.lo Would you like to confirm if the above proposed solution worked for you? If yes, can you accept the answer to help others know that it works. Otherwise let us know if you face any issue.